# Remote Desktop Sharing in Ubuntu 20.04 "frozen" when monitor is disconnected by KVM

Tags: remote-desktop, vncviewer

I am able to enable remote desktop in Ubuntu ([with Vino](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html.en)), and it works fine as long as the monitor is active.
When the KVM controlling the Ubuntu box is switched to a different system, the Remote Desktop session becomes "frozen".

A TightVNC viewer session will connect, and display the Ubuntu desktop. But any attempt to interact with mouse or keyboard is ignored.

How can I enable remote desktop to remain active and usable for a "headless" system, or when the KVM is switched away?