# VNC Server does not display application GUI

Tags: xfce, vnc, tightvncserver, vncviewer

I run a VNC Server on an ubuntu 18.04 linux desktop, and connect it using my Windows 10 PC, It was working just fine until I rebooted my server, now none of the applications open GUI, Clicking on "Open terminal here" does nothing, same for Applications while opening chrome. I am using Xfce as my OS

[image]

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311145/remote-desktop-sharing-in-ubuntu-20-04-frozen-when-monitor-is-disconnected-by/1311346#1311346) helps.

Comment: I think this has been answered https://askubuntu.com/questions/120973/how-do-i-start-vnc-server-on-boot#122864

Comment: @Raffa I already have the TNC server up and running, just applications don't open.

Comment: @mondotofu My desktop isn't frozen, everything works fine, just application windows don't display, like terminal, chrome. I am guessing it's trying to output to a different monitor, but I already set the output display, and nothing helped.

Comment: First thing I would try is to connect with an admin account instead of root, if this is your case. Can you check that?

Comment: @atlasan Hi, It was working fine with a root account before, so i don't think it would matter.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is the problem you are having and what is the relevance of VNC.
Is the problem you describe happening in the machine you use as a server? Or in a Remote desktop using Xrdp from Win 10?
Note that [Xfce](https://www.xfce.org/) is a desktop environment, not an OS.
Try opening a terminal from the shortcut usually available. You my have to install some utils from the console, with apt-get.

Comment: The issue is most likely happening with Xfce, since I can connect to my console with Putty just fine, so it is indeed an issue with the server.

Comment: I think the reason is you are using the root account which is not recommended and might not run well with graphical applications especially if those applications were installed by another admin account. Try connecting with a **non root** account and see if that helps.

Comment: @Raffa I have no other admin accounts, only a root account, so I would need to create another account just to test this. I'll take a look very soon.

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously recommend you look for a file in your home directory which logs the X-related errors. Either `.xsession-errors` or something in the `.vnc` folder.

Comment: Hello, I uploaded the .xsession-errors to a pastebin, could you take a look? https://pastebin.com/raw/TaeuBgSr