# Lubuntu 1804 LTS remote access

Tags: lubuntu

I would like to remote access from one Lubuntu 1804 LTS laptop to another Lubuntu 1804 LTS laptop over LAN only. I have read lots of posts about similar projects but they all seem to be out of date. I looked at the Lubuntu remote access wiki (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/RemoteDesktop) but vino-preferences & xtightvncviewer no longer work.
Can anyone give current, working, simple, straightforward options please?

Comment: Try [xrdp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311145/remote-desktop-sharing-in-ubuntu-20-04-frozen-when-monitor-is-disconnected-by/1311346#1311346)

Comment: You can use ssh, if you only want to do shell, or you could do VNC connect for full desktop

Comment: Just so you know, Lubuntu's support for 18.04 ends next month and there's no upgrade path between 18.04 and the currently supported versions of Lubuntu - it requires a fresh install (to go well, even though the system may offer to upgrade). The new Lubuntu uses LXQt and there are so many changes that upgrading the normal way isn't supported or advised.

Comment: If you'd provided the wiki links you mention, I would have looked them up and potentially corrected them (unless they were marked *depreciated* already as I suspect they were)

Comment: I have managed to upgrade my HP 255 to Lubuntu 20.04, but my Fujitsu Esprimo will not boot after fresh install. I have reinstalled 18.04 to it. I have now given up with idea of remote access, but thanks for your advice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [x2Go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) here, excellent software